# Choosing data from one Table that have similar data in another table

Tags: python, sql, r, data-cleaning

I have a very unusual question that involves matching data with similar values in two separate tables in SQL Server.
for example, I have two tables:

The first table contains the following data:

- JobID (int),
- AssignmentDate(date),Location(nvarchar(MAX))

The second table contains the following data:

- Date(date), Start_time(nvarchar(MAX)),
- End_Time(nvarchar(MAX)), Begining)Ometer(int),
- Ending_Ometer(int), Mileage(float),
- To_location_Address(nvarchar(MAX)).

I created the folllowing query in SQL to generate a view so I can examine the data for validity:

```
SELECT dbo.KodakITAssignments.AssignmentDate, 
       dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.Date,               
       dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.Start_Time, 
       dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.End_Time, 
       dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.Beginning_Odometer,                         
       dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.Ending_Odometer, 
       dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.Mileage_mi, 
       dbo.KodakITAssignments.JobID, 
       dbo.KodakITAssignments.Location, 
       dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.To_Location_Address
FROM dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019 RIGHT OUTER JOIN
     dbo.KodakITAssignments
     ON dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.Date = dbo.KodakITAssignments.AssignmentDate
```

My results are not quite satisfacotry.  Here is an example of my results:

```
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  8:51 PM 9:12 PM 89053   89062   9   125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   1701 Earl St, Union, NJ 07083
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  8:11 PM 8:18 PM 89052   89053   1.4 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   200 Varick St, New York, NY 10014
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  7:57 PM 8:01 PM 89051   89052   0.7 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   62 W 14th St, New York, NY 10011
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  7:39 PM 7:41 PM 89051   89051   0.3 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   14 6th Ave, New York, NY 10013
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  4:29 PM 4:50 PM 77846   77854   7.7 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   1701 Earl St, Union, NJ 07083
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  3:41 PM 3:42 PM 89051   89051   0.1 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   225 Broadway, Suite 2130, New York NY  10007
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  3:27 PM 3:28 PM 89051   89051   0.3 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   101 Barclay Street, New York, NY 10007
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  3:11 PM 3:28 PM 77843   77846   3.4 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   116 Elmer St, Westfield, NJ 07090
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  11:30 AM    11:40 AM    89049   89051   2.3 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   260 Broadway, New York, NY 10007
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  11:03 AM    11:24 AM    89037   89049   12.1    125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   175 12th St, Jersey City, NJ 07310
11/26/2019  11/26/2019  11:02 AM    11:17 AM    77837   77843   5.5 125272  114-116 Quimby Street, westfield, NJ 07090 ,Westfield ,US   570 South Ave East, Building G, Suite F, Cranford, NJ  07016
10/21/2019  10/21/2019  7:37 PM 7:48 PM 87965   87967   2.2 119748  41 Main St, Millburn, NJ 07041, USA ,US 1701 Earl St, Union, NJ 07083
```

I would like to keep records from KodakIT_all_trips_2019 where the City and Zip Copes from both Location are a match; however, I do not have an exact location data set in the columns.

How do I filter the data in this case?

I am open to using SQL, R or Python to filter the data; what ever approach works best is okay, as long as I wind-up with a single record for the KodakItAssignments record.

Thamk you for the reply and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose SQL to solve this problem.  I decided to create a View with RIGHT OUTER JOIN of the two tables and a WHERE and Like operator.

```
(dbo.TableA.Location LIKE '%' + RIGHT(dbo.KodakIT_all_trips_2019.To_Location_Address, 5) + '%')
```

My results were very close (98% satisfactory) because this query only produced most of the return trips (not all) because some trips started where I terminated and not from my original location. I needed to inspected the data and will probably have to write an additional query to collect the remaining data.  Overall, this was a very good start for my research.